# Create copy (duplicate) files on current folder for OneDrive (LIVE SDK API)

Tags: sdk, onedrive, live-sdk

On Javascript, I am using Live SDK REST API (this is an API for One Drive basic REST services as described here : https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh826531.aspx ) and I am trying to implement a "Make a copy of file/ duplicate" action, so to create duplicates (with changed names) on my current path.
When I am making a COPY request as here (where path is my file that I want to copy and destination is its current folder):

```
function copyFile_onClick() {
    WL.login({
        scope: "wl.skydrive_update"
    }).then(
    function (response) {
        WL.api({
            path: "file.a6b2a7e8f2515e5e.A6B2A7E8F2515E5E!141",
            method: "COPY",
            body: {
                destination: "folder.a6b2a7e8f2515e5e.A6B2A7E8F2515E5E!125"
            }
        }).then(
            function (response) {
                document.getElementById("infoArea").innerText = "Item copied.";
            }, 
            function (responseFailed) {
                document.getElementById("infoArea").innerText =
                    "Error calling API: " + responseFailed.error.message;
            }
        );
    },
    function (responseFailed) {
        document.getElementById("infoArea").innerText =
            "Login error: " + responseFailed.error_description;
    }
    );
}
```

I am getting error response, as resource already exists there (which is totally reasonable). However, I cannot find a way to add a filenameCopy1 parameter on the request so to avoid that.

So, the only way I am thinking to do the cloning is having a temp folder to copy the file, then rename it with filenameCopy1 and then move it back to the current folder. That process is really slow and not so safe (eg. what if only one action happens).

Any advice really appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: The [new api](https://dev.onedrive.com) supports the capability you're after. The `Live Connect` API isn't actively being developed, so I would definitely recommend switching if you can.

Comment: Thanks, finally I moved to the new OneDrive API. It s much more robust for all separate actions.
However, it was tricky because I had to manually add authentication windows for my application + some issues when copying files - the response was a location url (to monitor the copy progress) instead of data for copied file